# $C_{c}(X)$ is complete. then implies that $X$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff space .If $C_{c}(X)$ is complet,then $X$ is compact (this is to be proved). I know that $C_{c}(X)$ is dense in $C_{0}(X)$. As $C_{c}(X)$ is complete implies that $C_{c}(X)=C_{0}(X)$. and I know only urysohn's lemma and Tiez's extension theorem on locally compact Hausdorff spaces and other basic things.

Comment: Refresh my memory $C_C(X)$ is ?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Continuous functions with compact support.

Comment: One difficulty in proving the assertion is that it is not true. That's probably an unsurmountable difficulty. Is $X$ maybe assumed to also be $\sigma$-compact?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't true.  For instance, if $X=\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal, then $C_c(X)=C_0(X)$ is complete (since every continuous map $X\to \mathbb{R}$ is eventually constant), but $X$ is not compact.